# How do I monitor my PC and see what people do when they're on my PC?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to monitor an XP machine](https://superuser.com/questions/120869/how-to-monitor-an-xp-machine)

I need to know what people are doing when they use my PC?

The OS is Windows XP.

Comment: Can you provide a more explanation of what your problem is. As it currently stands your question is very likely going to get closed as "not a real question".

Comment: yes what websites/and otherinfo maybe what the wrote

Comment: If you're that concerned about people doing stuff on your computer, why are you letting them use the computer at all?

Comment: @ceejayoz many times husbands/wives will put this on a shared home PC if they believe the other is guilty of infidelity. (just one example)

Comment: If I were in that situation, I would simply ask my partner honestly. If you're in such a relationship where you need to spy on your partner, something's not right. That's my opinion anyway...

Comment: someone suggested this is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/120869/how-to-monitor-an-xp-machine

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [HandyCafe](http://www.handycafe.com/en/) more than Keyloggers. check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/120869/how-to-monitor-an-xp-machine/120876#120876). it may be also a similar question too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/).

Although it's rather meant for monitoring and tracking your own actions, it could also be used to track others on the same PC, and it might be easier than a keylogger to install and use.